# How much time it take to create partition table on wd green hdd?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

I'm creating partition table using KDE partition manager.

Formatting to NTFS but it doesn't yet done for creating file system of first drive dev/sda1.

It's been just running at process

`Job: Create file system 'ntfs' on partition '/dev/sda1' Command: mkfs.ntfs-quick -verbose /dev/sda1`

Since last 30 minutes.

Ext4 just fail within few seconds or minutes.

So I tried NTFS but it's been like that.
So does wd green hdd drive take such time to make even partition table?

Comment: Please confirm it's `mkfs.ntfs-quick -verbose /dev/sda1`. I would expect `mkfs.ntfs --quick --verbose /dev/sda1`. If there's a typo then you should [edit] and fix it.

Comment: Ext4 failed, right? So maybe there's a hardware issue. What was the error? No filesystem can heal or save a failing HDD.

Comment: No I'm not using command it is in details of gui application KDE partition manager.

Comment: And this GUI simply invokes more basic commands for you. I'm surprised it logs a command that looks invalid, that's all.

Comment: Don't know why it is incorrect.

Comment: To be clear: I'm not saying you should fix the command you run (or the GUI runs for you). I'm saying you should confirm the GUI really says what you claim in the question. Because what you claim in the question is not a command I would expect the KDE partition manager to run. Therefore I suspect *typos* (did you type by hand? or copy-paste?). But if you tell me this is *exactly* what the GUI printed then I will believe you.

Comment: Yes you are right the gui says it in log but I feel like or don't know if does this incorrect commands itself.

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts